# Shadows not working with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't make shadows work on this fiddle, tryed endless configurations.
I've seen other related questions, checked all the solutions and nothing...

I have:

```
this._box.castShadows = true;
floor.receiveShadow = true;
light.castShadow = true;
this._renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
this._renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peter7z/x9fu2e0m/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your spelling.

```
this._box.castShadow = true;
this._box.receiveShadow = true;
```

It would also be advisable to update to the current revision of three.js.

three.js r.93

Comment: Thank you! I hate how JS console logs very few errors.

Comment: This is not a javascript error. You can add properties at runtime. That what you did.